# Solve yields complex Root even if the domain is Reals

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I want to solve $x^3=a^2$ for $x$ where $a>0$ and $x$ is real. The answer I want is
$$x=a^{2/3}.$$
On Wolfram Cloud, I tried

```
Solve[x^3 == a^2, x, Reals, Assumptions -> {a > 0}] // ToRadicals
```

But this returns

```
{{x -> (-1)^(2/3) a^(2/3)}}
```

It appears that specifing the domain to `Reals` does not make `Solve` to return a real `Root`.

However, giving less assumptions to `Solve` do yield the correct answer among the other complex roots:

```
Solve[x^3 == a^2, x]
```

This returns

```
{{x -> a^(2/3)},{x -> -(-1)^(1/3) a^(2/3)},{x -> (-1)^(2/3) a^(2/3)}}
```

What modification do I need for the first command?

Comment: Assumptions is not valid for Solve.

Comment: @CarlWoll `Solve` has been recently upgraded to take `Assumptions` as an option [starting with version 12.2](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn122.html#99344334). That still wouldn't solve the problem at hand though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals) supports the undocumented option [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions). Making use of this option gives:

```
sol = Solve[x^3==a^2,x,Reals]
ToRadicals[sol, Assumptions -> a>0]
```

> {{x -> Root[-a^2 + #1^3 &, 1]}}

> {{x -> a^(2/3)}}